# Is doing a 1 year MBA after many years of experience in the IT industry worth it?

Tags: masters, india

I have over 13 years of experience in IT industry, but no consistent domain / specialization. I have worked as UI developer, project manager, scrum master, business analyst, recruiter, etc. for few years each. Now my career seems stuck and I am not getting further on the career ladder.

I couldn't go to college due to financial constraint in my early years. I am 35 now, but the itch to attend a regular university is still there. I want to do a regular MBA (preferably 1 year) from a foreign university. (I am a native Indian).

Sometimes I think that doing an MBA might give a kick to my stalled career. But these are my fears / constraints.

- I still do not have enough money. My entire life's saving is around 45K USD. Should I do MBA or not? If yes, should I go for an ed loan (saving my current money for unforseen events) or empty my bank accounts (to avoid paying interest)?
- If I leave my job now, with current slow economy, what will be the ROI of doing a 1 year MBA?
- As per my little research Germany is a country for students (less tuition fee)! If I go for non-US universities (like Germany, Spain, Australia, NZ) I will have to learn their native language to survive there, which needs another 6-8 months.

**TL;DR**
Please advise if doing a 1 year regular MBA after 13 years of experience worth it? Which universities with good rankings offer affordable MBA?

Comment: _I couldn't go to college due to financial constraint in my early years_ Do you have Bachelors degree?

Comment: Yes, I have bachelors through an evening college (which is not welcomed in India). This is another reason I want to do full-time MBA.

Comment: While your question is not strictly off topic, I think people from IT industry could much better answer you how much an MBA worth with your experience.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are unsure of what you want from a MBA, besides hoping it might kickstart your career. I think it's important that you first identify exactly what you want from a MBA - your goals. Do you want to gain connections with others in your field? Do you want a job that requires a MBA? After you have identify these goals, ask yourself if a MBA at a certain institution will help you achieve these goals. The degree itself is just as important as where you get the degree. Foreign universities might be cheap, but degrees that come with it might not be highly regarded in the States.

Studying abroad is not the optimal choice in your situation. As a native American, there are plenty of prestigious American institutions willing to diversify their graduation class and scholarships will be available to you - you just have to search or ask for it. Going abroad for only 1 year is definitely not worth the trouble of learning a new language - it will be a distraction to your studies.

I would also disagree with you that the economy in the US is slow. Are there particular reasons why you feel that way?

Comment: I believe the OP is from India, not a native American.